# Session management across various web applications deployed in jboss 5.1

Tags: java, session, jboss

I currently have two applications deployed in Jboss server. I want to deploy another web application in the same server.  The objective of adding one more application is to implement OAuth and create session with the user info.

Is it possible for the existing two applications to consume the session created by my new application with minimal or no code changes?